# FUNCTION test.TO_DATE does not exist помогите решить проблемы

Tags: mysql

```
SQL-запрос:

База данных Mysql

INSERT INTO EMP
VALUES ( 7369,  'SMITH', TO_DATE(

'17-12-1948',  'dd-mm-yyyy'
) )
```

Comment: а какая база данных?

Answer (score 3):

В mysql нет функции TO_DATE

Используйте `STR_TO_DATE('17-12-1948','%d-%m-%Y')`